# Multiple processes management

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, process, multiprocessing

just wanted to know what the best approach would be:
let's say I have 3 processes, each one of them does its job, calculates and passes data to a final process whose function is that of taking the data from the other processes and populating a DB.

The reason for leaving the final process by itself is that the 3 other processes may take a variable time to complete, so I want each one of them to pass data to the final one as soon as it has completed its job in order to avoid wasting time, and I don't want multiple processes to write the DB at the same time. 
But to do this, each process need to know whether the final process is busy or not, and in case it is available send their data, otherwise wait for it to complete before sending.
My idea is to use 'whenever' gem and create 3 processes that would run on their own, but I am puzzled by the last one as I don't know much about daemons and the like, and I know I might be making all of this much more complicated than it really is.

Any suggestion is welcome, thank you.

Comment: FYI: Your problem sound like the intention I had. To avoid a lot of parallel db write requests I used the sidekiq gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I can provide some insight into your problem. My dev team uses a home-grown messaging que that's backed by our database. That means that messages (job metadata) are stored in our `messages` table.

Our rails app then creates a daemon process using the [daemons](https://rubygems.org/gems/daemons/versions/1.2.2) gem. It makes instantiating daemon processes much simpler.There's no need to be afraid of what daemo processes are; they are just linux/unix processes that run in the background.

**You specifically mention that you don't want multiple processes to write to your db** It really sounds like you are concerned about deadlock issues from multiple daemons trying to read/write to the same table (please correct me if you are not, so I can modify my answer).

In order to avoid this issue, you can use [row-level locking](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/row-level-locking) for your messages table. That way a daemon doesn't have to lock the entire table every time it wants to see if there are any jobs to pick up.

You also mention using 3 processes (I also call them daemons out of habit) to perform a task, then once those three are done, notify another process. you could possibly implement this functionality as a specific/unique message left by your 3 workers.

For example: worker A finished his job, so he writes a custom message to the `special_messages_table`. Workers B and C finish there task, and also write to this table. Now the entire time these daemons are processing, your third daemon would be polling the `special_messages_table` to see if any combination of these three jobs had finished. Once it detects that they have, it could then start.

This is just a rough outline of how you can use daemon processes to accomplish what you are asking. If you provide more details I would be happy to refine my answer. Don't be afraid of daemons!

Comment: Thank you, thisis very useful, and what I was looking for! You are also right in supposing that I am trying to avoid deadlock issues and I will look further into row-level locking. I will try the special_message_table approach as it seems to fit exactly what I need!
Thak you again, I will let you know if I finally overcome my fear of the daemons! :D

Comment: Great @Jack, glad I could help. It should also be mentioned that using a database backed message queue doesn't scale well, and if your application ever needs to scale drastically I recommend Sidekiq or RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind! I would ask you one more clarification if I may: what are the differences between a process run by sidekiq or whenever and a Daemon? Don't they both run in the background as different processes? I am trying to understand what benefits will each solution bring to my case. Thank you again!

Comment: So it's important to understand the relationship between threads and processes. Threads belong to a process, and threads of the same process share memory. Processes have threads, and those threads all die when their associated process is killed. Sidekiq actually uses threads instead of processes. This gives you a noticeable performance over processes because every time a new process is forked your OS must copy the address space of the original process to a new process. This is time consuming.